# Generics , force type Void when extended subclass eventually does not need to be aware of type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types, void

An abstract class is declared as

```
 myClass<E extends Number, D extends Number>
```

Sublasses are

```
 final mySubClass<Double,Integer>
 final myOtherSubclass<Double,Double>
```

Imagine there is a subclass that will not have a parametrized procedure for the first type, I mean, type would be ignored. Is there any way to set it to Void, Null or something?

```
final mySubClassThatDontUseFirstType<Void,Integer>
```

For example, if it had a inner List<E> inside, this list would be List because would be never used.

Comment: **Everything** `extends Object` and BTW writing `extends Object` is for that very reason redundant. Your abstract class cannot be declared as you say because wildcards are not accepted in class declaration. This question is only semi-clear to me.

Comment: Sorry you are right for the wildards, I changed it. It is an example, I could use more abstract temrinology than Object. And what I am not sure is Void extends Objects, that is why I ask, beause I saw people using somethign like Void in other places

Comment: `Void` is nothing but yet another class, which is **not** a subclass of `Number`. That's why this cannot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Is there any way to set it to Void, Null or something?***

No, not really. What ever you choose it needs to be a subtype of `Number` (that's simply a requirement of the Java Language).

What you could do is to create an uninstantiable class `VoidNumber`

```
class VoidNumber extends Number {

    // Private constructor
    private VoidNumber() {
    }

    ...
}
```

and use that to document the fact that it's not used.

Comment: OK if Void extends Object then I understand I have to change the example Type. If Void type exists why doesnt compile?

Answer (score 1):

> I think the problem is Void does not extend Object, because if not If I think it works

Ofcourse class `java.lang.Void` extends `Object`, just like any other Java class extends `Object`.

Note that `Void` is not the same as `void`. `Void` with a capital `V` is a little bit like the wrapper classes for primitive types (`int` -> `Integer`, `long` -> `Long` etc.).

Beware that the compiler treats `Void` like any other class. That means if you have a method that returns `Void`, it must return a value; for example, the method must end somewhere with `return null;`. It's not like `void`, which the compiler understands as "nothing is returned".